# How to get the value with v-select, options loaded from ajax using slot templates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-select

I am trying to get the selected value to update in my vue component, but it doesn't change and stays empty instead, i can select things but i can't do anything with it.

I have tried adding `:value` to the `v-select` component, but it just doesn't update the value whenever i select something.

Since i am still trying this with the example from their documentation, i made a fork on codepen here: https://codepen.io/andyftp/pen/GweKpP so you can try it out.

Anyone can help me here?

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select - Ajax</h1>
  <v-select label="name" 
            :filterable="false" 
            :options="options" 
            :selected="selected"
            @search="onSearch"
     ><template slot="no-options">
      type to search GitHub repositories..
    </template>
    <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
      <div class="d-center">
        <img :src='option.owner.avatar_url'/> 
        {{ option.full_name }}
        </div>
    </template>
    <template slot="selected-option" scope="option">
      <div class="selected d-center">
        <img :src='option.owner.avatar_url'/> 
        {{ option.full_name }}
      </div>
    </template>
  </v-select>
  Selected: {{ selected }}
</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component("v-select", VueSelect.VueSelect);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: null, // this needs to be filled with the selected value (id or object), but it stays empty
    options: []
  },
  methods: {
    onSearch(search, loading) {
      loading(true);
      this.search(loading, search, this);
    },
    search: _.debounce((loading, search, vm) => {
      fetch(
        `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${escape(search)}`
      ).then(res => {
        res.json().then(json => (vm.options = json.items));
        loading(false);
      });
    }, 350)
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `v-model="selected"`?

Comment: @HusamIbrahim That i didn't think of that, you are a genius sir, thank you.